# How do I install apps (.apk files) that are placed in my Xperia U's internal memory?

Tags: installation

I have Xperia U. I copied 2-3 games, their .apk files to be precise, to my internal storage. How can I run them? I have not installed them yet.

Comment: Please do not use all caps.

Comment: What are these files? APK files? or data (savegame) files?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Updating the firmware

Sony Xperia U has official firmware upgrade to ICS (4.0.4, I believe).
Connect you phone to your PC and run [Sony PC Companion](http://www.sonymobile.com/in/tools/pc-companion/). From there you can update your phone to ICS.

Warning: Always take a backup in PC companion before updating firmware.

### 2. Installing APKs which are not from market

To enable installation of applications which are not from market, please follow the steps

> - go to **Menu** > **Settings** > **Applications** and make sure    “**Unknown sources**” is checked.
> - Open a file manager and click on the APK which want to install and in    the dialog box click install.
> - Open the application from application drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone to your PC and run Sony PC suit.
and update your firmware

take backup of contacts, messages, notes etc.

just go to your file explorer and run then select verify and install or package installer.

if it says enable unknown app installation

```
    go to Menu -> Settings -> Security -> Applications and check “Unknown sources”.
```